# Adapter pattern apply with JsonObject

Tags: design-patterns, json, kotlin

The purpose of the code is to apply adapter pattern to put an extra feature for searching through json object.
I hate deep nested json object because it makes my code look messy when access through each node. I made an adapter class that can search through this deep json. So basically instead of having this messy code

```
val result = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("user")
      .getAsJsonObject("address")
      .getAsJsonObject("home")
      .getAsJsonArray("rooms")
      .first()
      .asJsonObject
      .getAsJsonObject("another_one")
      .getAsJsonArray("and_another")
      .first()
      .asString // etc...
```

you will have nice and clean query string in one line.

```
val query = "user.address.home.rooms[0].another_one.and_another[0]"
val result = JsonObjectAdapter(jsonObject).search<String>(query)
```

My adapter class

```
/**
 * Adapter for any json object class
 *
 * @param T type of json object
 * @property json target json object
 */
abstract class JsonAdapter<T> {

    var json: T

    constructor(json: T) {
      this.json = json
    }

    /**
     * search through each json node and return the result
     *
     * @param query string to search the json
     * @param R type of result
     */
    inline fun <reified R> search(query: String): R {
        val keys = query.split(".")
        val traverseKey = keys.subList(0, keys.size - 1)
        val lastNode = traverseKey.fold(json) { acc, field ->
            val pattern = Regex("(.*?)[(\\d+)]")
            if (pattern.matches(field)) {
                val group = pattern.find(field)!!.groupValues
                val target = group.first()
                val index = group.last() as Int
                parseJsonArray(acc, target, index)
            }
            else {
                parseJsonObject(acc, field)
            }
        }

        return parseResult(lastNode, keys.last(), R::class)
    }

    /**
     * parse json array format according to the json object type
     *
     * @param node current json node
     * @param key key to retrieve the next node
     * @param index target array index
     */
    abstract fun parseJsonArray(node: T, key: String, index: Int): T;

    /**
     * parse json array format according to the json object type
     *
     * @param node current json node
     * @param key key to retrieve the next node
     */
    abstract fun parseJsonObject(node: T, key: String): T;

    /**
     * parse the result to the result type
     *
     * @param lastNode last json node
     * @param key key to retrieve value
     */
    abstract fun <R> parseResult(lastNode: T, key: String, type: KClass<*>): R;
}

class JsonObjectAdapter : JsonAdapter<JsonObject> {

    constructor(json: JsonObject): super(json) {
      this.json = json
    }

    override fun parseJsonArray(node: JsonObject, key: String, index: Int): JsonObject {
        return node.getAsJsonArray(key)[index].asJsonObject
    }

    override fun parseJsonObject(node: JsonObject, key: String): JsonObject {
        return node.getAsJsonObject(key)
    }

    override fun <R> parseResult(lastNode: JsonObject, key: String, type: KClass<*>): R {
      return when(type) {
        Int::class -> lastNode.get(key).asNumber as R
        else -> lastNode.get(key).asString as R
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the adapter pattern, you can use the power of [Kotlin's extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions) to accomplish what you want.

```
fun <reified R> JsonObject.search(query: String): R {
    // You can use `this.` here and apply any magic that you want
    // You can even call other methods here and pass `this` along
}
```

If you were to use the Jackson library, they have a built-in function for this:

```
val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
val tree = mapper.readTree("""{ "hello": { "world": [{}, { "here": { "i": { "am": 42 } } }] } }""")
println(tree.at("/hello")) // Returns an ObjectNode
println(tree.at("/hello/world")) // Returns an ArrayNode
println(tree.at("/hello/world/1")) // Returns an ObjectNode
println(tree.at("/hello/world/1/here")) // Returns an ObjectNode
println(tree.at("/hello/world/1/here/i")) // Returns an ObjectNode
println(tree.at("/hello/world/1/here/i/am").asInt()) // Prints 42
```

Comment: That's great idea will take a note!

Comment: @Patrick Also added a note about existing functionality in the Jackson library that you can use out of the box